# file browser for webdav ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, webdav

I have been looking for a packet/library with a file browsing capability for WebDAV, which I could use for my project in objective c, using xcode 5.1. so far the best I have found is GDFileManagerKit. but it still has stuff unsupported by my ARC such as AFNetworking version used. I do not want to alt the code of this library since it requires many changes. I would like to know if there is a better library or without me having to use AFNetworking version 1.

Thank you and please bear with me if this question is very novice. I am new to objective c xcode and iOS

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of several free libraries, for example WTClient. Yet, every library I have seen is not using ARC, instead managing memory without the garbage collector.

Comment: I tried WClient but it is still has the same problem. in addition it does not have a file browsing capability